# Does Flux's ult interrupt?

Tags: heroes-of-newerth

When people are channeling with homecoming stones or abilities, will Flux's global ult interrupt them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it does NOT interrupt channeling abilities.

None of Flux's spells contain a mini-stun.

Some channeling abilities (like Tempest's ultimate) are interrupted for the simple reason the hero has moved too far from the cast target.

Comment: I've seen an enemy Flux ultimate cause a fail Forsaken Archer ultimate to turn into a win ultimate, moving her into a great position to get several kills.